# How does small discrete steps between rotational energy states make integration accurate?

Tags: energy, discrete, quantum-states, quantum-statistics

I understood that if the distance between the discrete rotational energy states are very small, the number of quantum states can be approached accurately using integration of the same formula. This is according to the Euler-Maclaurin formula explained on page 2-3 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/12_562ln08.pdf). However, I keep deducing the opposite for the cumulative number of quantum states.

**Here’s why**

The degeneracy $g$ at a rotational energy $E$ is:
$$g(E)=\sqrt{1+\frac{8\mu r^2\cdot E}{\hbar^2}}$$
This can be deduced by solving the quadratic formula $J(J+1)= \frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}E$ to get $J$ in terms of $E$ and then substituting that in the degeneracy formula $g(J)=2J+1$.The formulas are shown on page 8 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/11_562ln08.pdf).

If the steps between de discrete energies are very small, being $dE$, then I'd deduce that the *exact* cumulative number of quantum states all up to a certain energy state $|E_p|$ (i.e. adding all the degeneracies) is equal to:
$$g(\geq |E_p|)=\sum^{E_p/dE}_{n=0}\sqrt{1+\frac{8\mu r^2 \cdot n \cdot dE}{\hbar^2}}$$
This calculation should then be accurately approached by integrating $g(E)$ up to $E_p$.
$$g(\geq E_p)=\int_0^{E_p}\sqrt{1+\frac{8\mu r^2\cdot E}{\hbar^2}}\cdot dE$$
However, plotting $\frac{g(\geq |E_p|) - g(\geq E_p)}{g(\geq |E_p|)}$ shows that the percentage difference increases if I make the $dE$ in the summation smaller. You can slide de value of $dE$ [here to see this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ei8zuxinmg) ($dE$ is written as $d$)

What is wrong with my deduction?

Comment: Your summation equation is wrong. Try to start with your integral equation and think about discretizing it. You shouldn’t have a dE inside a sqrt.

Comment: Can you tell me some literature for your expression of g, please ? I am not familiar with this one.

Comment: @Martin Apologies, this can be deduced by solving the quadratic formula $J(J+1)= \frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}E$ to get $J$ in terms of $E$ and then substituting that in the degeneracy formula $g(J)=2J+1$.The formulas are shown on page 8 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/11_562ln08.pdf)

Comment: @JahanClaes I wrote $dE$ in the summation as an expression for a very small value, Shouldn't that reach the outcome of the integration if it's small enough? I don't know how I should express the summation in very small steps otherwise.
I was able to to discretize the integration but I would have to use floor functions, or divide the integration by $dE$ to make it approach the summation outcomes. 

I don't know what I'm missing..

Comment: Have you noticed that your integral and your sum have different units? You're trying to compare $\sum g(E)$ with $\int g(E) dE$. You're comparing a sum of degeneracies with a sum of (degeneracy$\times$an energy interval). You either need to compute $\sum g(E)\Delta E$ or $\int\frac{dg}{dE}dE$ in order to make the units match.

Comment: @probably_someone That's what I was thinking but according to the Euler-Maclaurin Summation formula this shouldn't matter if the spaces are very close. Please check end of page 2 and start of page 3 [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/12_562ln08.pdf). The summation of $f(J)$ is clearly written as an integration of the exact same formula times $dJ$ (the other additive parameters are eventually thrown out because they can be neglected).

Comment: @johnnygui there is an implicit $\Delta J$ in the summation, which they don’t write out since it is one.

Comment: @JahanClaes Should I therefore sum the derivative $\frac{dg}{dE}$ times a $\Delta E$ instead?

Comment: @JahanClaes  Your approach doesn't give the correct density of states, which is the derivative of $g(\geq E)$, not the derivative of $g(E)$. 
You're saying that$$g(\geq E_p)=\int_0^{E_p} \frac{dg(E)}{dE}\cdot dE
$$Then the density of states is $\frac{dg(E)}{dE}$ But this [source](https://tinyurl.com/y84a6ef7) says for a 2D rotator the density of states function is
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{\sqrt{2\mu R^2}}$$
If $g(\geq E)$ is expressed as in my OP then this gives the correct function, but then the units don't agree and the summation differs from the integration

Comment: @probably_someone Please see my above comment about the consequences of correcting the units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to start from the beginning: the sum of a function over some integers can be thought of as a crude estimate of the area under that function.

Suppose you had a function $f(x)$, and you wanted to estimate the value of $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ for some integers $a$ and $b$. Making that estimate involves the following steps:

1. Choose some division of the interval $[a,b]$ into a bunch of non-overlapping sub-intervals.
2. For each sub-interval, choose some representative value $f(x_n)$ for that interval (there are many possible choices: the value at the left edge, the value in the center, the value at the right edge, etc.)
3. For each sub-interval, multiply $f(x_n)$ by the width of the sub-interval $\Delta x_n$ (in other words, we're approximating this sub-interval as a rectangle with a height equal to the representative value of $f(x)$ in that sub-interval).
4. Add together the areas $f(x_n)\Delta x_n$ for all sub-intervals.

So, for example, if $a=0$ and $b=10$, I could choose a division of the interval $[0,10]$ into 100 sub-intervals of width $\Delta x_n=0.1$. Choosing $x_n$ to be the right edge of each interval, I would arrive at the estimate

$$\int_0^{10} f(x)dx\approx\sum_{n=1}^{100}f(x_n)\Delta x_n=\sum_{n=1}^{100}f(0.1n)\times0.1$$

Now, suppose I chose to divide the interval $[0,10]$ into only 10 sub-intervals instead. Then $\Delta x_n=1$, and the estimate looks like the following:

$$\int_0^{10}f(x)dx\approx\sum_{n=1}^{10}f(x_n)\Delta x_n=\sum_{n=1}^{10}f(n)\times1=\sum_{n=1}^{10}f(n)$$

So now you can clearly see that the integral is approximated by the sum over the integers, and conversely, you can see that the sum over the integers is approximated by the integral. Of course, this isn't a very good approximation when there are only 10 subdivisions we're summing over. But, if we fix the width of our subdivisions as $\Delta x_n=1$, then summing over the interval $[0,1000]$ gives us 1000 subdivisions, and summing over the interval $[0,10^{6}]$ gives us 1 million subdivisions, so at that point the value of the sum and the value of the integral are quite close to one another.

---

This is exactly what's happening in this problem. The sum

$$\sum_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}}g(J)$$

is the same thing as the estimate for an integral

$$\sum_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}}g(J)\Delta J$$

with $\Delta J=1$. So what integral in particular is this estimating? Well, as we saw above, we can choose any point inside our sub-intervals as the representative point. If the integers $J$ represent the right edge of our sub-intervals, then this is an estimate for the integral over $[J_{min}-1,J_{max}]$. On the other hand, if the integers $J$ represent the left edge of our sub-intervals, then this is an estimate for the integral over $[J_{min},J_{max}+1]$. Allowing for any choice, the sum above is an estimate for the integral over $[J_{min}-\epsilon, J_{max}+1-\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon$ between $0$ and $1$. So, in the most general case, we can write the following:

$$\int_{J_{min}-\epsilon}^{J_{max}+1-\epsilon} g(J)dJ\approx \sum_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}} g(J)\Delta J=\sum_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}}g(J)$$

Now, let's rewrite the integral as follows:

$$\int_{J_{min}-\epsilon}^{J_{max}+1-\epsilon}g(J)dJ=\int_{J_{min}-\epsilon}^{J_{min}}g(J)dJ+\int_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}}g(J)dJ+\int_{J_{max}}^{J_{max}+1-\epsilon}g(J)dJ$$

The two outer integrals have a total width less than 1. Since we're using subdivisions with width 1 in our estimate already, it doesn't hurt our precision to simply treat these as single rectangles with representative heights $g(J_{min})$ and $g(J_{max})$. So we can write:

$$\int_{J_{min}-\epsilon}^{J_{max}+1-\epsilon}g(J)dJ=g(J_{min})\epsilon+\int_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}}g(J)dJ+g(J_{max})(1-\epsilon)$$

Your course notes choose $\epsilon=1/2$, which is the choice I will use from now on; combining our last expression with the approximation from earlier, we can now write:

$$\sum_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}}g(J) \approx \int_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}} g(J)dJ + \frac{1}{2}(g(J_{min})+g(J_{max}))$$

which is the expression arrived at in your course notes. The two boundary terms are small in the limit of large $J$ intervals, and I will be ignoring them for the rest of this answer.

---

So now that we know how the sum and integral relate, we can derive the equivalent relations in terms of energy. As you said, the density of states as a function of energy is:

$$g(E)=\sqrt{\frac{8\mu R^2E}{\hbar^2}+1}$$

and the relation between $J$ and $E$ is given by:

$$J=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{8\mu R^2 E}{\hbar^2}+1}-1$$

So if you want to find the equivalent sum in terms of $E$ values, you have to substitute for $J$ in the expression $\sum_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}}g(J)\Delta J$. Substituting for $J$ in $g(J)$ simply gives you $g(E)$ as above, and converting $\Delta J$ will still only give you a factor of $1$ after substitution (remember, $\Delta J$ is the difference in the $J$-value corresponding to the different energies, which we have chosen to be the energy values corresponding to $J$ values that are 1 apart), so the equivalent sum is simply

$$\sum_{n=0}^{|J_{max}-J_{min}|}g(E_n)$$

where $E_n=E(J_{min}+n)$. If you examine the formula for $E(J)$, you will notice that **our sub-intervals in energy are not uniform in width**. This means that something in the integral has to change when changing coordinates.

If we want to evaluate an equivalent integral, we must substitute for $J$ in the expression $\int_{J_{min}}^{J_{max}}g(J)dJ$. Now, we don't have the freedom to choose non-uniform subdivisions to reflect the fact that our coordinates have changed; instead, the effect of the non-uniform subdivisions emerge in the conversion from $dJ$ to $dE$. In particular:

$$dJ=\frac{dJ}{dE}dE=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{8\mu R^2E}{\hbar^2}+1}}\frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}dE$$

So, in conclusion, the correct approximation to the sum in terms of energy is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{|J_{max}-J_{min}|}g(E_n)\approx \int_{E_{min}}^{E_{max}}\frac{g(E)}{\sqrt{\frac{8\mu R^2E}{\hbar^2}+1}}\frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}dE=\int_{E_{min}}^{E_{max}}\frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}dE=\frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}(E_{max}-E_{min})$$

As you can see, the units now match up, and the percent error should behave much better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation! One question; How does this explain that an integration is more accurate to the summation if the energy states spacing are very close, as stated by the [course notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/lecture-notes/12_562ln08.pdf)? You were able to accurately transform the summation of $J$ into an integration while the $J$ steps are relatively large (integers).

Comment: @JohnnyGui When you're judging the accuracy of a Riemann sum approximation to an integral, what matters is not the absolute size of the steps, but the size of the steps _as a fraction of the total range_. For a million integers, each subdivision is one millionth the width of the total range, which leads to a very accurate approximation.

Comment: This helped me, thanks. One very last (a bit of a random) question if you don't mind. Is it in general actually possible to derive $f(E)$ from an equation such as: $$f(E)\cdot dE=\sqrt{1+\frac{8\mu R^2 \cdot E}{\hbar^2}}$$ Or does such an equation not make sense?

Comment: @JohnnyGui The units don't match on either side of that equation, and in any case it's highly unusual to have a differential on one side and not on the other.

Comment: I was considering $f(E)$ to have units of $1/E$ (just like the derivative of $g(E)$) such that the units would agree. I was testing another approach by saying that in the continuous realm $$g(E) = g(E\geq E+dE)$$ and equating this to some function $f(E)\cdot dE$ so that integration of $f(E)$ would give $g(\geq E)$. But your answer hints that this statement is wrong in the first place.

Comment: @JohnnyGui Given that $g(E\leq E_0)=\int_{0}^{E_0}\frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}dE$, and you want $f(E)$ such that $g(E\leq E_0)=\int_{0}^{E_0} f(E)dE$, we have that $f(E)=\frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}$.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed what I noticed myself which convinced me that $$\frac{2\mu R^2}{\hbar^2}\cdot dE\neq\sqrt{1+\frac{8\mu R^2 \cdot E}{\hbar^2}}$$

Comment: @JohnnyGui As I said already, that isolated $dE$ doesn't make any sense. If you have a differential in an equation, it must either be inside an integral or there must be another differential on the other side. In other words, either $Adx=Bdy$ or $\int A dx = B$, for expressions $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I know, I was showing with the unequal $\neq$ sign that I'm convinced my deduced equation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, but I noticed something. The integration doesn't include $Jmin$ for its outcome as opposed to its summation equivalent. Excluding $Jmin$ makes sense in the realm of counting quantum states _starting_ from $Jmin$.
But then I'd have to add $Jmin+1$ as the lower limit in the summation equivalent to meet this quantum states counting logic.
But in this case, the accuracy does **not** depend on the interval width but on how high $jmax$ and $jmin$ are independently, as shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ygrtx5w3xm)
Is this the accuracy behaviour when counting quantum states?

Comment: I forgot to tag you. Sorry for bothering you again, I'm quite curious about my above question.